# why my image is moved instead of creating multiple images

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to show the same image on a few locations on my newly opened window using this:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

for i in range(len(entities) + 1):
  img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
  panel = tkinter.Label(root, image = img) 
  panel.grid(row = i, column = i)
```

This indeed displays the first image, but only moves it around, instead of creating new images. How can I fix that?

Comment: Help you helpers with a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it!

I used a list instead, to store the images and then treat each one separately by changing my code to:

```
entity_images = []
for i in range(len(entities)):
  img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
  entity_images.append(img)
  panel = tkinter.Label(root, image = entity_images[i]) 
  panel.grid(row = i, column = i)
```